# Conversion of Latitude-longitude to EPSG 3106

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a location in longitude and latitude is
Latitude: 24.095818 and Longitude: 90.412521.

I want to convert it to EPSG:3106 in Excel.
Can you please help me with the formula with detailed calculations?

Comment: Excel is a bad choice for this, look at proj, gdal or QGis

Comment: You sound ambitious. Here you go:  
http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/guid7.html  
https://www.iogp.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/373-07-02.pdf

Comment: Transverse Mercator is a relatively complicated projection. More recent version of Pointdump's 2nd link is on [this page](https://epsg.org/guidance-notes.html). Also, are the lat-lon coordinates already in Gulshan 303 or are they in WGS84 or ITRFxx? If the latter, you would also need to implement the geocentric translation (2D) method wihch includes converting lat-lon to XYZ and back.